# Filtering out/saving a term from an equation by using its factor (in multiplication)

Tags: python

I have the following equation/term:

```
1 + (a2*b2*c1 - a2*b2 + a2*c2 + 2)/λ + (a2*c2 + 1)/λ**2
```

I would like to save: `(a2*c2 + 1`) as `a`
and `(a2*b2*c1 - a2*b2 + a2*c2 + 2)` as `b`.

However, `a` and `b` vary each time. Hence, I need an algorithm which can separate a and b from the above equation using the "indicators" `λ**2` and `λ` respectively. My idea is something along the lines: if multiplication contains `λ**2` or `λ` then ...

Comment: you have this 1 + (a2b2c1 - a2b2 + a2c2 + 2)/λ + (a2*c2 + 1)/λ**2 as a string?

Comment: With sympy you can define symbols and use them as constants in your calculations. All variables (a2, b2 etc.) are defined as symbols here.